# What does the param "axis" do in Scale Layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I understand that Scale Layer works as `z = x * y` where `y` is "broadcasted" to match the shape of `x`.

Here is my question:

I have `bottom[0]` size as `N*C*H*W`, with `bottom[1`] as `N*1*H*W`,

and I want to tile `bottom[1]` to `N*C*H*W`, then computing the element-wise product.

How should I set the parameters, especially `"axis"`?

Thx a lot.

Comment: Looking at [this document](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/scale.html) it would seem that `"Scale"` layer does not support such element-wise multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [scale_layer.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/scale_layer.cpp) axis is the starting axis for scaling:

```
axis_ = bottom[0]->CanonicalAxisIndex(param.axis());
...
const vector<int>::const_iterator& shape_start =
        bottom[0]->shape().begin() + axis_;
const vector<int>::const_iterator& shape_end =
        (num_axes == -1) ? bottom[0]->shape().end() : (shape_start + num_axes);
vector<int> scale_shape(shape_start, shape_end);
```

So, in your case you can set axis parameter to either 0 or 1.
There is also another parameter `num_axis`, which from my understanding, is the number of axes that are scaled. In your case, it can be set to 2 or 1 depending on you axis parameter. (`axis=1, num_axis=1` or `axis =0, num_axis=2`).

I have never used this layer, and these conclusions are only based on the source code of scale_layer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not hundred percent sure. But you could try two things. In concat layer, axis = 0, means the first dimension(N) in your N * C * H * W, and axis = 1, means second dimension (C). so you could try with axis = 1, and scale parameter of 3. I am not completely sure. But you could try and let me know what you get.

Another thing you can try is to use Concat layer with axis = 1.